# SQL Server 2012 CTE Bug?

Tags: sql-server

I think I found a bug in SQL Server 2012. I have the following complex query that uses CTE with row_number to accomplish paging, followed by a subquery to return total rows in a single query:

```
with data as ( ...complex query with row_number() ... as rowNumber... )
select *, (select count(*) from data) as totalRows 
from data
where rowNumber between 1 and 10
```

What I'm finding in my specific query is that if the final query returns 5 rows, the totalRows comes back as 8. But there are only 5 rows. How could totalRows be bigger than the number of rows returned? I've tried query hints like disabling parallel execution plans but not only is it slower, it's still not right. Could I be doing something wrong or is this a bug? Is there another way to get the count back in one query?

Comment: You are not applying your filter 1 to 10 against the select count(*) from data.     If you re do this as a temp table instead of a CTE you may see how a CTE really works.   I would not use RowNumber without the partition and over clause

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the internals of your query and ensuring you're partitioning statements are well written...

I'd suggest you are getting differences because of your where clauses. You need to be consistent and use either:

```
with data as ( ...complex query with row_number() ... as rowNumber... )
select *, (select count(*) from data where rowNumber between 1 and 10) as totalRows 
from data
    where rowNumber between 1 and 10
```

or

```
with data as ( ...complex query with row_number() ... as rowNumber... )
select *, (select count(*) from data) as totalRows 
from data
```

Comment: Thanks but this misses the point. I'm asking for one page of data which is 10 rows long, but I also want to get back the count of all rows so I can setup a pager showing "rows 1-10 of 235" for example. I wouldn't need to ask for that count if I just wanted the rows - I could simply count them on the client-side.

Comment: I guessed that your where clause might be for paging results, but if the count is returning a different value than the returned rows, you must have a try at the queries I've posted to see if things become consistent. Then when you look at the returned data, you might be able to work out where something is going wrong in your "complex query with row_number()". My guess is that you are ending up with gaps in your rowNumbers.